# Why doesn't TypeScript enforce async/await on promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following code. `performAsyncAction` performs an async action and returns `Promise<Response>`. In `someFunction` , I was surprised that TypeScript doesn't warn about *not* using await on a function that returns a promise.

```
function performAsyncAction() {
  return fetch('someservice');
}

function someFunction() {
    const result = performAsyncAction(); // Was expecting typescript to give error here
}
```

I found a relevant linting rule that may help [promise-function-async](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md)

Comment: There's no error, `result` is a Promise, there's no await there

Comment: Why should it? Storing promises to, for example, run them in parallel with `Promise.all()` is a perfectly valid use case. TS can't predict why you're storing a promise as opposed to awaiting it

Comment: If typescript would enforce `await`, how would you do `Promise.all()`? Sometimes you still want to deal with Promises.

Comment: @Thomas Not sure what you are asking, you can `await` a `Promise.all()` call. See https://dev.to/jamesliudotcc/how-to-use-async-await-with-map-and-promise-all-1gb5

Comment: but how do you get Promises into the array you pass to `Promise.all()` if typesctipt / a linter would force you to `await` everything that returns a Promise?

Comment: @Thomas Having a hard time following your thoughts and how they're relevant to the OP's question.  Isn't the OP just forgetting to use `await?`

Comment: @JuanMendes: Thomas is basically saying the same thing as Klaycon.

Comment: Maybe the way to think about this is that typescript is about syntax, and awaiting a promise is about semantics.  Whether to block execution for a result is a design question.

Comment: I guess Klaycon and Thomas are assuming the OP thinks everything that returns a Promise is magically going to be awaited and unwrapped? Then what would the `await` keyword be for? I don't see how the question makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an error, it is intended behaviour.

1. The Promises existed long before async/await, you have several ways how to handle them
2. Awaiting promise is internal logic of function, not requirement
3. Typescript knows well that you have Promise and not the value inside that Promise, so it will warn you if you want to use it in a wrong way
4. The function you have provided is not `async`, therefore it is not even possible to await there
5. await/async and Promises are the same thing in Javascript, it does not matter if you `await` Promise or if you `.then` Promise, its only syntactic sugar (useful one though)
6. There is a lot of cases where you dont want to await newly created Promise, i.e. to allow processing of several Promises at once, thus reducing the time of processing request

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree with you. In my experience forgetting about awaiting a promise is the source of majority of problems, especially with handling errors.

Although `await/async` syntax exists in pure JS, it would make perfect sense to introduce another syntax sugar that would notify the TS compiler you intend to leave the promise to run 'in-the-background'.

This, as any of the other strict checks, would be optional.

E.g.

```html
async function someFunction() {
   const result = performAsyncAction(); // Compilation error
}

async function someFunction() {
   const result = along performAsyncAction(); // Returns promise
}

async function someFunction() {
   const result = await performAsyncAction(); // Awaits the promise
}
```